# Nonparametric test suggestion for distribution comparison

Tags: distributions, nonparametric

I am not sure if this is appropriate place to ask, but I appreciate any help on this issue. I want to compare the distributions of the results of the two experiments played by the same group of people. I would like to get an advice about what are the possible non-parametric tests for this purpose. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The standard non-parametric test for comparing two distributions is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. This is a well understood test which is frequently taught, and so it may well be a good place to start. The basic idea is to look at the ECDFs of the two samples, and if they are far apart, the distributions are probably different. Distance in the KS test is measured as the furthest apart the two ECDFs are.

Then there are improvements on the KS test. The Cramer-Von Mises test is more powerful in general. It consists of summing up all the distance between the ECDFs everywhere there are points in the joint sample. Anderson-Darling does the same thing but then also adjusts the differences based on our knowledge of the variance of ECDFs.

I've stayed within very agnostic tests which claim no information whatsoever about the two distributions. There are whole classes of tests which work well when you know something more -- like that the distributions are continuous, or so forth. That said -- you can do very well with a working two-sample Anderson-Darling test.

One last note -- Kolmogorov-Smirnov is notoriously underpowered in finite samples, so do try to run a version of it which is based on permutation/randomization rather than the asymtotic approximation.